# Can I restric access to the Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I would like to restrict access to [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) by using the IP address of the connection source.

Can I restrict access by using the settings of GCP products such as Access Context Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to limit access to the Firebase console for a project to a specific IP address (at least not that I know off).

You can limit *who* can access the project and what they can do in the project, but not where they do it from.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to block access to Firebase console by following [Secure the Google Cloud console and the Google Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp-enterprise/docs/securing-console-and-apis)

Please note that it will also restrict access to Google Cloud console and the Google Cloud APIs for configured group.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).